# C# Ebay API ReviseFixedPriceItemCall Description Not Updating

Tags: c#, ebay-api

So we all know the eBay active content change is coming up here soon.  I'm trying to update my listing descriptions to remove the active content.  My calls are not failing, but they do not seem to be updating the description.  I've tried ReviseFixedPriceItemCall and ReviseItemCall with no success.  I've tried changing the options of the DescriptionReviseMode with no success.  Any help would be appreciated.  This is what I currently have that is going through without any errors, but does not update the description.  Thanks in advance.

```
var reviseFp = new ReviseFixedPriceItemCall(oContext2);
            //var reviseFp = new ReviseItemCall(oContext2);
            var item = new ItemType { ItemID = myId, Description = newDescription };
            item.DescriptionReviseModeSpecified = true;
            item.DescriptionReviseMode = DescriptionReviseModeCodeType.Replace;


            reviseFp.Item = item;

            try
            {
                reviseFp.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myId + " : " + ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: I think issue is in **DescriptionReviseModeSpecified**, this attribute is not available in eBay API. you can check in below link.http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.DescriptionReviseMode

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this code works perfectly fine.  I was trying to have the javascript removed for the active content changed, but it was never being removed.  Well just manually going and editing the listing from eBay itself would not remove the javascript either.  So it wasn't the code at all it was the listing.  I got on the horn with eBay support and they couldn't remove it either.